# Size of a structure considering padding with strings and int as element

Tags: c, struct, padding, sizeof

I want to know how the following structure is stored in memory.
The given structure size is shown 28 by using `sizeof()`. I want to know why it is so?

```
typedef struct {
    char a[10];
    int c;
    char b[10];
}example4;

printf("%ld\n", sizeof(example4));
```

I already know about padding, but don't know how does it apply for strings with different length.
I used the following printf to know the memory address

```
printf("%p %p %p %p %p\n", (void*)&(example4.a), (void*)&(example4.b), (void*)&(example4.c), (void*)&(example4.a[0]), (void*)&(example4.b[0]));
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: _"but it didn't work."_ - to improve the quality of the question you should mention what exactly didnt work. In this case you get a compiler error (due to the fact I explained in my answer below), so you should post the exact error you get.

Comment: What didn't work? The printf should have made it clear. 12 bytes for `a` (2 bytes padding), 4 bytes for `c` and 12 bytes for `b` (2 bytes padding).

Comment: Instead of printing addresses, you are probably more itnerested in the offsets. Take a look at `offsetof()` from `stddef.h`. It evaluates to a value of type `size_t` that can be pritned using `%zu` specifier.

Answer (score 3):

You get a compiler error, because in order to print addresses of variables you need a concrete instance (and `example4` is a type, not an instance):

```
example4 ex4;
printf("%p %p %p %p %p\n", 
                  (void*)&(ex4.a), 
                  (void*)&(ex4.b), 
                  (void*)&(ex4.c), 
                  (void*)&(ex4.a[0]), 
                  (void*)&(ex4.b[0]));
```

This is the output I get (**specific in my environment**):

```
000000707F55F6B8 000000707F55F6C8 000000707F55F6C4 000000707F55F6B8 000000707F55F6C8
```

**So the layout I infer (again in my environment) is:**
`a` - 12 bytes (with padding)
`c` - 4 bytes
`b` - 12 bytes (with padding)
Total: **28 bytes** (which matches the result reported in your test).

*(it's a bit confusing because the fields names are not according to they position in the struct, but I followed you code as is)*.

Note that layout can change between compilers and systems but my result seem to be in line with yours and therefore explains what you observed.

Another issue is that the proper `printf` format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`:

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(example4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Layout of the structures can be easily explored using the `offsetof` macro from `stddef.h`. The program below will output the results you want on pretty much every mainstream platform.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char a[10];
    int c;
    char b[10];
} Example4;

int main() {
    printf("a:     %zu\n", offsetof(Example4, a));
    printf("c:     %zu\n", offsetof(Example4, c));
    printf("b:     %zu\n", offsetof(Example4, b));
    printf("total: %zu\n", sizeof(Example4));
}
```